# How to create a formula to calculate SUM of columns from DOWN to UP direction

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'd like to create a formula that can show me the SUM in next column of all ROWS in a COLUMN but I want it show the SUM from DOWN to UP Direction.

Here is a screen shot attached to understand my requirements:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Advice on text annotations on a picture: they are part of the question, but are unreadable to screen-readers, search engine robots, and clipboards. Please try to avoid them unless they are essential - you can just put markers like A and B, and then reference them in your paragraph text.

Answer (score 0):

Use `=SUM($C$2:$C2)` in `D2` and `=SUM($C2:$C$16)` in `E2`

Or more dynamical use  `=SUM($C2:INDEX(C:C,MAX(IF(C:C<>"",ROW(C:C)))` in `E2`

Answer (score 0):

In E2 put:

```
=SUM(C:C)-SUM($C$1:$C1)
```

This will subtract the running total from the grand total.